# Is there an online service which translates text from English to 'Hinglish'?

Tags: translation, transliteration

'Hinglish' = Hindi + English(written script of english)

Translation from English to Hindi: Hi -> नमस्ते

Translation from English to ‘Hinglish’: Hi -> Namaste

Basically, I need to translate text but in same written script.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/hi/) is actually capable of this.

[image]

For higher quality translation, you are, of course, going to need to hire a professional translator.

Comment: Thanks! Does this thing apply to a folder translate in google translate?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. The quickest way to find out is to try it.